# In formal writing, is there any difference between "couple" and "some"?

Tags: word-choice, formality

For example in a résumé, are

> Experience in a couple of rendering tools

and

> Experience in some rendering tools

the same from the point of view of formality?

Comment: _Some_ is suitable for any context; _a couple_, when it simply signifies _a few_, is too informal, and possibly inaccurate, because it can be interpreted literally as a minimum requirement of _no more than two_. _A few_ is better and less informal.

Comment: In formal language, a couple refers to -exactly- two items. Informally is where the number can get slippery.

Comment: To me, "a couple" sounds informal even when it means exactly "two." I'd use the noun "couple" in formal writing only to mean two people who are paired together.

Comment: Ok, I'll use `some` then.

Comment: Pretty please stop using backticked monospace on ELU.

Comment: You might care to have a look at [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/what-does-a-couple-mean-to-you-and-what-does-a-few-mean-to-you) related question.

Comment: I'm wondering whether "Experience in ..." ought to be "Experienced in ...", or "Experience of ...". I'd prefer the former. Also, if there are only two then why not name them?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I haven't said there are only two. They may be 4, 5, 6...this is just an example.

Comment: @yzT If there are 4, 5, or more then I'd certainly not say "a couple" then.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest neither are correct in formal writing. As commentors have already pointed out, in this instance 'a couple' would refer to literally two items. However, 'some' also feels clumsy to me in that sentence.

I would suggest using one of the following in a formal document, such as a resume:

> Experience in *a number of* rendering tools.
>
> Experience *with various* rendering tools.
>
> Experience in *numerous* rendering tools.
>
> Experience in *a multitude of* rendering tools.

I have ordered these in roughly ascending order of number, with "a number of" being the least, and "a multitude of" being the most, depending on how many tools you wish to express your experience with.

I might also suggest changing the word "in" to "with" in any of these sentences.

Comment: You could even use 'many' if you were so inclined.

Comment: Or "with several"