# few followed by fewer issue?

Tags: grammar, semantics

"In X, few had been to town Y. Even fewer aspired to go to town Z."

Are these two sentences together correct?

Few technically means a small number that could be as low as zero. Based on that, does "even fewer" in the second sentence makes sense?

@Araucaria : Exactly right. "few" is entirely different than "a few", which means a non-zero number. But when only "few" is used, it can communicate a very small number, if any. (so it can include zero).

@mitch, tromano, dusty, oldbag:
In the first sentence above, "few" can mean zero. There is lot of solid literature behind it i think based on a quick search.

So, using "even fewer" in the second sentence then incorrect/correct; why?

Comment: 'Few' does not techincally mean 'as low as zero'. In fact, there is no -technical- meaning of few. It is vaguely a low number. The implication is that there are some, but not 0. This is not explicit but something inferred. 'Few' is not a range, but rather is an exact number which just is not exactly known. If zero were possible value, then one would be compelled to say 'few to none'.

Comment: 'Few' means 'zero' only when used ironically: *Few pigs can fly*.

Comment: @mitch Here "few" can include zero.

Comment: @tromano, The ironic sense of few holds whenever it is used with article "a". "a few" means entirely than "few" which includes zero.

Comment: @Joe Black: I think you meant to say "The ironic sense of *few* holds whenever it is used *without* the article 'a' " ?

Comment: When talking about numbers in a *non-ironic* mode, 'few' can never mean zero, and it can never mean one; I would even go so far as to say that it must mean at least three. *Few people in the room were drinking.*  *Few people in the audience understood why the zombie started singing the National Anthem.*

Comment: @TRomano Hmmm "*Few if any*" definitely seems to allow the possibility of zero, one or two. The *one or two* there are supplied by the *few* not the *if any*, I'd reckon?

Comment: ^true. "few, if any" supports the idea that "few" can very well be zero if anything. If "few" didn't include zero, then "if any" would be superfluous.

Comment: @Araucaria On the contrary: *few if any* may be paraphrased *if not zero then few*, which clearly excludes zero*.

Comment: @Araucaria: I understand *few if any* to mean 'If any, it won't be many.'  As StoneyB says, "any"  =  "more than none".  That could be a lot more or a little more than none, so it's possible that *any* could be more than *few*. :-)

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, exactly - *any* covers the zero, but the possibility of *one* and *two* is met by *few* :) imo that is

Comment: @Araucaria You having fun? :D (Of course, there's the top of page 394 in the 2002 *CGEL* which touches on this topic, but then that would ruin all the fun, now wouldn't it.)

Comment: If as low as zero equals "no one" in X has been to Y then "even fewer" have been to Z is just a rhetorical, facetious statement, which might work if the context is meant to be humorous or ironic.

Answer (score 3):

The implicature of unqualified *few* is 'more than one': it always takes a plural.

And that it never implicates *none* may be inferred from the frequency with which it is paired with the contrastive *if any*:

> Few people, if any, had been to town Y.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I agree with the assertion that 'few' could be zero.  Most dictionaries I quickly consulted indicated at least "more than one". See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/what-does-a-couple-mean-to-you-and-what-does-a-few-mean-to-you) for discussion of few vs. couple vs. some, etc.

So I believe the two sentences are fine.

Comment: Helpful post. However, that question is not about *few* but ***a** few* which is a completely different item with a completely different grammar!

Comment: @araucaria, correct. I clarified this for others in the edit of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Even if we assume that "few" can be zero, we never assume that it can *only* be zero -- at least, not without further context.

The second sentence offers further context.  We start with one small number that (for the sake of argument) may or may not be zero.  We then have a smaller number (which itself may or may not be zero) which supplies additional information and shows that the first small number is not zero in this case.  This specific "few" is at least one, and this specific "fewer" is at least zero.

> A few villagers -- at least three but never more than five -- stand guard each night to keep the wolves at bay.

It's no mistake when context narrows our interpretation of some word or phrase.  That's exactly what we expect context to do.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially speaking (US): "The server forgot to give me a straw for my drink, so I went over and grabbed..." *a couple*(2), *a few* (>2-<5), *a handful* (5,or so)
*a bunch* or *a mess* (6-10)

Comment: That's ***a** few* -  which has a different meaning from *few*, although it's similar.

Comment: @araucaria, correct.