# A word between "several" and "many"

Tags: single-word-requests

- One
- Couple
- Few
- Some
- Several
- (Any word that fits in here?)
- Many
- ...

Example sentence:
A cycle time of ___ seconds is achievable.

(___ here means a quantity around, say, 10 to 30.)

Comment: If you look at the comparison graph at [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/438822/4972) it seems that 'a lot' is perceived to be in between 'several' and 'many'

Answer (score 1):

The only word that comes to mind between several and many is *numerous*. But, inserting that into your example sentence feels a little awkward to me. I think you might be better served by simply saying "A cycle time of 10 to 30 seconds is achievable." Especially in light of the fact that pieces of technical writing should, in my opinion, avoid the usage of vague terms like the others in your list.

If you're set on using an adjective, you might consider reworking the sentence to give yourself some other options. For example, "A *significant*/*substantial* cycle time is achievable.

Comment: "Numerous" is more of a synonym of "many".

Answer (score 1):

**a fair few** OED:

> **P.1.e.** *colloquial*
>
> **(a) Used as noun: a considerable number; also with of-phrase as complement.**
>
> 2006   L. Welsh Bullet Trick (2007) 77   *Glasgow's got a hostelry on every street corner and **a fair few** in between.*

Comment: Or the more common (in the U.S.) "quite a few."  I'm not sure either answer is any different from "several," or that there is an answer to this question.  I wonder if the OP is looking for something like "not a ton"?