# What is the exact meaning of 'give me a pair of'?

Tags: meaning, expressions, formality

Does a pair always means '2 of something' or can it be used more generically to indicate 'a few of something'? What is the exact amount indicated by 'a pair'?

Is there a different meaning whether a pair is used in formal or in informal language?

Comment: That is a not a full question. Kindly post a full question. You might want to visit the HELP section to see what questions to avoid.

Comment: A special case is when one "unit" consists of two similar parts: a pair of glasses, scissors, shoes, gloves, dice, etc.

Comment: @DjinTonic Oddly enough, I have never heard "Give me a pair of pants"

Comment: Two pants. Here is my take. English tends to use fewer words if possible. Having a pair pants vs pants, just seems unnecessarily verbose. I could understand if there were regional differences though.

Comment: Removed comment for James: Wouldn't you say "I bought two pairs of pants" rather than "... two pants"?

Comment: It is idiomatic, depending on geography. Asking for the "exact meaning" without providing minimum research is off-topic.

Comment: @DjinTonic How is a pair of dice an example of your special case? How are they not just two dice?

Comment: @RosieF You are correct--my goof.

Comment: Related: [What does “a couple” mean to you, and what does “a few” mean to you?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1858/191178)

Comment: _(A) coupla_ will get the paucal meaning 'a few' across. _(A) pair of_ either refers to items that are bifurcated, like pants or binoculars, or items that are purchased and used in pairs, like shoes or earpods.

Comment: As usual, Mari-Lou A was ahead of me. See her answer.

Answer (score 3):

The OP is asking whether "a pair" can signify more than two things. Generally speaking it cannot but there will always be the odd exception; however, for now none come to mind.

The term *couple* is less fixed:

> *I'd like **[a couple](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/couple) of** oranges*, please.

This can suggest any number of oranges between two and four.

But **a pair (of)** will nearly always be two of something that are parallel to each other. They will look identical to each other and will be used together.

- A pair of scissors/ glasses/ gloves/ socks/ shoes and so on.

Comment: However, a *pair of parakeets* or a *pair of (matching) vases* signifies two items, whereas a *pair of glasses*, etc. signifies one item.

Comment: And what about a pair of shoes? It doesn't mean one shoe. "They make a nice pair" can be said of two people in love too.

Comment: Correct. However, I think there is a difference. You need to say "two (pairs of) scissors" to get two.

Comment: This reminds me of the shoe store sign "Buy one, get one free."